# What does 'typeof' operator tells here?

Tags: javascript, typeof

The code is:

```
 var someVariable;    // this variable is declared but not initialised...

 alert(typeof someVariable);   // alerts 'undefined'
 alert(typeof notDeclared);    // also alerts 'undefined' irrespective 
                               //  of the fact it has not been declared..
```

It seems a bit confusing. Now, if I do

```
alert(someVariable);    // again alerts 'undefined'
alert(notDeclared);     // causes an error
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gjYZt/2/

If 'typeof notDeclared' is undefined, then when I alert 'notDeclared', it should also alert 'undefined' instead of giving an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer:

`typeof` has a special case for unresolvable references; it explicitly returns `undefined` if the reference is unresolvable.

### Long answer:

The typeof operator has a special case for unresolvable references:

> #### 11.4.3 The typeof Operator
>
> The production *UnaryExpression* : `typeof` *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *val* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. If Type(*val*) is Reference, then
>
>    1. If IsUnresolvableReference(*val*) is `true`, return "`undefined`".
>    2. Let *val* be GetValue(*val*).
> 3. Return a String determined by Type(*val*) according to Table 20.

On the other hand, the internal `GetValue(V)` function, which is used everywhere in javascript, including for retrieving the value of a varialbe, throws a ReferenceError if the reference is unresolvable:

> #### 8.7.1 GetValue (V)
>
> 1. If Type(*V*) is not Reference, return *V*.
> 2. Let base be the result of calling GetBase(*V*).
> 3. If IsUnresolvableReference(*V*), throw a `ReferenceError` exception.
> 4. If IsPropertyReference(*V*), then
>      [...]

See [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

`someVariable` is declared `not initialized`.But  `notDeclared` is not declared..

`someVariable` does not contain any default value .But `notDeclared` is not avialable.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `typeof` doesn't signal an error for `notDeclared`. But I didn't downvote.

Comment: ok thanks for information.It is good to give explanation when you gave a down vote

Answer (score 1):

> When I do 'alert(typeof notDeclared);', that should also give an
>   error. Isn't it?

No, because [the specification is clear](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) that if the operand to `typeof` is not resolvable, the result of `typeof` must be `undefined` (look at 2a).

When you try to evaluate an expression that is not resolvable such as `notDeclared` in your example, you get a ReferenceError -- this is also according to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

the  operator typeof returns the type of the operand.

This list summarizes the possible return values of typeof

```
Type    Result  
Undefined   "undefined"   
Null    "object"  
Boolean "boolean"  
Number  "number"  
String  "string"  
Host object (provided by the JS environment)    Implementation-dependent  
Function object (implements [[Call]] in ECMA-262 terms) "function"  
E4X XML object  "xml"  
E4X XMLList object  "xml"    
Any other object    "object"
```

if yout alert return undefined that's because your variable type is undifined.

Regards

Comment: Where does that say that it doesn't signal an error if given a nonexistent variable?

Comment: @RobG Sure, but that's not in his answer.